# How to join these two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This query gets several `AssignmentId's`

```
SELECT AS2.AssignmentId
FROM dbo.AssignmentSummary AS AS2
WHERE AS2.SixweekPosition = 1 AND AS2.TeacherId = 'mggarcia'
```

This query gets a value for only one assignment through the variable `@assignmentId`

```
SELECT S.StudentId, 
        CASE WHEN OW.OverwrittenScore IS NOT NULL
            THEN OW.OverwrittenScore
            ELSE dbo.GetFinalScore(S.StudentId, @assignmentId)
        END AS FinalScore
FROM dbo.Students AS S
LEFT JOIN dbo.OverwrittenScores AS OW
    ON S.StudentId = OW.StudentID
    AND OW.AssignmentId = @assignmentId
WHERE S.ClassId IN (
    SELECT C.ClassId
    FROM Classes AS C
    WHERE C.TeacherId = @teacherId
)
```

As I pointed, in the last query works when you assign a value through the variable and returns a table. Now I want to get a table of several `AssignmentId's` from the first query.

What do I need? A Join table? I have no idea about what to do now.

Comment: What does dbo.GetFinalScore() do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND OW.AssignmentId IN
(
    SELECT AS2.AssignmentId
    FROM   dbo.AssignmentSummary AS AS2
    WHERE  AS2.SixweekPosition = 1 AND AS2.TeacherId = 'mggarcia'
)
```

*the suggestion can be optimize if you can tell me how are the tables are related with each other.*

Comment: What do you need that I provide you?

Comment: a simple explanation on how the tables are related with each other. on what column are they linked? etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them using `in`:

```
SELECT S.StudentId, 
        CASE WHEN OW.OverwrittenScore IS NOT NULL
            THEN OW.OverwrittenScore
            ELSE dbo.GetFinalScore(S.StudentId, @assignmentId)
        END AS FinalScore
FROM dbo.Students AS S
LEFT JOIN dbo.OverwrittenScores AS OW
    ON S.StudentId = OW.StudentID
    AND OW.AssignmentId in (SELECT AS2.AssignmentId
                            FROM dbo.AssignmentSummary AS AS2
                            WHERE AS2.SixweekPosition = 1 AND AS2.TeacherId = 'mggarcia'
                           )
WHERE S.ClassId IN (
    SELECT C.ClassId
    FROM Classes AS C
    WHERE C.TeacherId = @teacherId
)
```

There may be ways to simplify this query.  This does a direct conversion of substituting the first query into the second.

Answer (score 1):

Use [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator with correlated subquery. Also you can replace CASE expression to function ISNULL.

```
SELECT S.StudentId, 
       ISNULL(o.OverwrittenScore, dbo.GetFinalScore(S.StudentId, o.AssignmentId)) AS FinalScore
FROM dbo.Students AS S
  OUTER APPLY (
               SELECT OW.OverwrittenScore, AS2.AssignmentId
               FROM dbo.OverwrittenScores AS OW JOIN dbo.AssignmentSummary AS AS2
                 ON OW.AssignmentId = AS2.AssignmentId
               WHERE AS2.SixweekPosition = 1 AND AS2.TeacherId = 'mggarcia'
                 AND S.StudentId = OW.StudentID
               ) o
WHERE S.ClassId IN (
                    SELECT C.ClassId
                    FROM Classes AS C
                    WHERE C.TeacherId = @teacherId
                    )
```